# Solidity error 'Invalid number of parameters for "undefined" '

Tags: javascript, node.js, automated-tests, blockchain, solidity

I'm trying to follow along with one of the solidity tutorials on youtube. And I'm getting stuck at [this](https://youtu.be/99pYGpTWcXM?t=3714) particular moment.

This is a solidity code:

```
    pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
    
    import "./Token.sol";
    
    contract EthSwap {
        string public name = "EthSwap Instant Exchange";
        Token public token;
    
        constructor(Token _token) public {
            token = _token;
        }
    }
```

Here is a deployment code:

```
const Token = artifacts.require("Token");
const EthSwap = artifacts.require("EthSwap");

module.exports = async function(deployer) {
  // Deploy Token
  await deployer.deploy(Token);
  const token = await Token.deployed()

  // Deploy EthSwap
  await deployer.deploy(EthSwap, token.address);
  const ethSwap = await EthSwap.deployed()

  // Transfer all tokens to EthSwap (1 million)
  await token.transfer(ethSwap.address, '1000000000000000000000000')
};
```

And this is a code for automated test:

```
const Token = artifacts.require("Token");
const EthSwap = artifacts.require("EthSwap");

require('chai')
    .use(require('chai-as-promised'))
    .should()

function tokens(n) {
    return web3.utils.toWei(n, 'ether');
}

contract('EthSwap', (accounts) => {
    let token, ethSwap

    before(async () => {
        token = await Token.new()
        ethSwap = await EthSwap.new(token.address)
        // Transfer all tokens to EthSwap (1 million)
        await token.transfer(ethSwap.address, tokens('1000000'))
    })

    describe('Token deployment', async () => {
        it('contract has a name', async () => {
            let token = await Token.new()
            const name = await token.name()
            assert.equal(name, 'DApp Token')
        })
    })

    describe('EthSwap deployment', async () => {
        it('contract has a name', async () => {
            let ethSwap = await EthSwap.new()
            const name = await ethSwap.name()
            assert.equal(name, 'EthSwap Instant Exchange')
        })

        it('contract has tokens', async () => {
            let balance = await token.balanceOf(ethSwap.address)
            assert.equal(balance.toString(), tokens('1000000'))
        })
    })
})
```

The test runed normally before I added this code to the solidity code:

```
    constructor(Token _token) public {
        token = _token;
    }
```

Now I get the following in my terminal:

> 2 passing (559ms)
> 1 failing
>
> 1. Contract: EthSwap
>    EthSwap deployment
>    contract has a name:
>    Invalid number of parameters for "undefined". Got 0 expected 1!
>    Error
>    at PromiEvent (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\contract\lib\promievent.js:9:1)
>    at C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\contract\lib\execute.js:223:1
>    at Function.new (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\contract\lib\contract\constructorMethods.js:57:1)
>    at _callee4$ (C:/Users/user/eth_swap/test/EthSwap.test.js:32:24)
>    at tryCatch (node_modules@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:45:40)
>    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (node_modules@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:271:22)
>    at Generator.prototype. [as next] (node_modules@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:97:21)
>    at step (test\EthSwap.test.js:3:191)
>    at C:\Users\user\eth_swap\test\EthSwap.test.js:3:437
>    at new Promise ()
>    at Context. (test\EthSwap.test.js:3:99)
>    at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:466:21)

Can someone explane what might be the problem. It seems that I did everything exactly as done in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Your contract has `constructor` function set. `constructor` function means when you initalize an instance, you have to pass arguments that used in `constructor(Token _token)`. this argument probably is the "address". So in your deployment function

```
 await deployer.deploy(Token);
```

you have to pass the `token` as the second argument

```
 await deployer.deploy(Token,tokenAddress);
```

if you needed more arguments, you would just pass them in order. first argument is the contract, then arguments in constructor, and the last argument is the options object if needed